# SQL have all result to one field

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

If you can please help me out, I have the code below.  The query is working fine...for example the results will be:

```
 1. item1
 2. item2
 3. item3
 4. etc
```

Is it possible for my query to output everything in one row?  Like:

```
1. item1, item2,item3, etc .....

SELECT tblExtras.extDescr 
    FROM (tblBuses INNER JOIN tblBusJoinExtra ON tblBuses.busID = tblBusJoinExtra.busID) INNER JOIN tblExtras ON tblBusJoinExtra.extID = tblExtras.extID
    WHERE tblBuses.busID = 1
```

Comment: This is not easy in MS Access.  Just do the reformatting at the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have solved it!

```
   TRANSFORM IIF(IsNull(First(tblExtras.extDescr)),'' ,First(tblExtras.extDescr) & ', '  ) AS extDescr
    SELECT tblBuses.busID 
    FROM (tblBuses INNER JOIN tblBusJoinExtra ON tblBuses.busID = tblBusJoinExtra.busID) INNER JOIN tblExtras ON tblBusJoinExtra.extID = tblExtras.extID
    WHERE tblBuses.busID = 1
    GROUP BY tblBuses.bUSid
    PIVOT 'tblExtras.extDescr' & tblExtras.extID;
```

Answer (score 0):

So your SQL query will deliver several data sets, in your special case all with one column. You could have selected additional data, such as price of the extra or whatever you still provide in your database, then you would have received several rows each containing description and price (or whatever you selected).

So in the end, you will process the results of the request by iterating over all the data sets you received, extracting the required information from them and do with it whatever you need to, most probably visualize to the user in some way.